Bathroom Fan broken - cannot take out fan!
would really like some help/advice here.
We brought our condo new construction about 11 years ago, and the bathroom fan recently stopped working. I got two handyman's to come out here already, and neither one knows how to take it out. The fan appears to be seated in a box/rack of some sort, and is bolted above the ceiling. The box/rack appears to be able to (quick) release the fan - but after many hours of trying everything, it doesn't budge at all.  We're at our wits end, and really don't want to take down a chunk of the ceiling to reach and replace the fan.
I've included photos and a video below.  The video is taking above the ceiling (through a small hole for light fixture), and in the video, the "box" is situated on the left side (of the video) all the way in the back, and you can see where the exhaust tube comes out.  The big dark thing on the right when the video pans right is a light bulb housing.
I'm probably using all the wrong terminologies and such, so I apologize in advance if I'm making this even more confusing.
Any suggestions/advice would be much appreciated.
Photos and video posted here: https://imgur.com/a/Vnl61XW
Note: the last photo (with the long air duct) is my my neighbor who had the same problem, but according to her, since her air duct is longer, her handyman was able to "push the old fan to the side and install a new one"?
PS since it's a condo building, I asked the maintenance team if they know how to get this out (I can't be the only one with this problem, right!?!?!), and was told that these fans don't break often and therefore are installed like a fixture and not meant to be replaced.  What!?!?!?

Get the condo maintenance team in to take it out or fix it.

@crip659, Things like exhaust fans and lights that are in a unit are not the responsibility of the maintenance team.

I live in a condo and had this issue. It was not fun, but it was doable.
Try this:  See where my pic has the 2 blue arrows.  There is usually a screw or 2 on the opposite side that helps anchor the chassis.  After the screw/s are out pry the metallip down. If the fan doesn't have the screws, or still will not come down, pry by the blue arrows. The chassis may be held in entirely by tabs.  You may have to use pliers and unscrew the screw in the side ( shown in red), to get room to pull the chassis down.
Getting all the tabs out of the slots sometimes takes much force and forceful words, but that is what is needed to remove the main fan chassis.  After that is out,  getting to the other parts is much easier and involves unscrewing screws and prying out mounting bars.  However, you may get lucky and your new fan may be able to be mounted in the existing box.  Get the new fan first and have the person doing the work check to see if mounting in the box is an option.


Yep.  Here's a video of a commonly used fan, showing how to remove the motor chassis, which may help OP visualize the technique: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bz1sDv6uXko

Thank you for the detailed instructions - will def try this!!!
